# Excel Automation in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office

I know that there are millions of posts about this already but I cant seem to find one that mirrors my issue.

I am using VS2010 and want to automate excel and I'm trying to work through the example here.

[MS Tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

The problem is when I go to add the reference as mentioned

> 3.Add a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library. To do this, follow these steps: •On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
>   •On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Excel Object Library, and click Select.

There is no such reference available.

Could someone please let me know if this is the right way to automate excel with VS2010.

If it is could someone please let me know why I dont have the COM option for excel.

Im wanting to write in VB.net but if someone has an example in C# that would be fine.

Kind Regards

Ash

I have tried implementing automation using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application dll but i get the following exception when I try to create the excel application.

This line generates the error.

```
EXL = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

This is the exception

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
```

Comment: Is Excel installed on your PC? Which version?

Comment: You need to specify the installation of these libraries when you are installing Excel, not Visual Studio.

Comment: I have Excel 2010 installed on my machine. Do I need to download some extra files then? Would these files need distributing with the program I produce?

Comment: Consider using the Mircosoft.Office.Interop.Excel Namespace under the .Net tab in the Add Reference form (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll).

Comment: No alias could you please post an example of how to achieve simple interop using the Mircosoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 2010 installed on your machine but still don't see it in the COM tab then there are reasonable odds that you have the 64-bit version of Office installed.  Visual Studio is a 32-bit program, it cannot see the registry entries for 64-bit COM servers.

Workarounds are to use the primary interop assembly, it ought to be installed on your machine.  Use the .NET tab and select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Next option is to import the type library directly.  Use the Browse tab and navigate to c:\program files\microsoft office\office14 and select excel.exe.  Set the Copy Local property of the added references to True to avoid having to deploy the PIA to the target machine.

Also be sure that your app can run as a 64-bit process.  In vb.net that's selected with Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options, set Target CPU to "AnyCPU".

Comment: Under the COM tab I have an option to add "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object library" is this what I should be looking for?

Comment: No.  So, do you have the 64-bit version of Office?  Did you follow my recommendation about setting the Target CPU option?

Comment: I have set the CPu and I still cannot see the Microsoft Excel Object Library. As far as I know I dont have 64 bit version... I do have student and home edition though. Not sure if this would make a difference.

Comment: The Target CPU doesn't have an effect on the dialog.  It makes sure that you won't get the `Class not registered` exception at runtime.  You are not responding to my requests for details, good luck with it!

Comment: Hans... In your answer you did not indicate what changes changing the compile options to ANYCPU would bring about so please dont say that Im not posting detail. What info have you requested that I have negleted to supply?